# ANOVA Basics in R

Tags: r, anova, lm

I have a data table `data`. The column `y` is numeric and the column `x` is character. I create one model with an intercept and one without:

`lmIntercept <- lm(y ~ x, data)`

`lmNoIntercept <- lm(y ~ x - 1, data)`

These models should be equivalent since we only have categorical predictors. I manually confirm that the coefficients of the models indeed are equivalent (basically: coefficient in model without intercept = intercept + coefficient in model with intercept). I also confirm that the fitted values are the same.

However, the $R^2$ of the two models are different (in this post I will use the same notation as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions). To me, this seems impossible:

**Q1** The models have the same fitted values so $R^2$ cannot change?

Note that I'm not considering the adjusted $R^2$ but just the ordinary.

To get to the bottom of this, I want to actually look at the ANOVA table with $SS_{tot}$ and $SS_{res}$. Thus using the function `anova()` I see that the `Sum sq` for `x` changes significantly between the models.

**Q2** Isn't this number (the `Sum sq` for `x`) supposed to just be $SS_{tot}$ or am I not reading the ANOVA table correctly? Manually calculating $SS_{tot}$ I get a very different number compared to what is in the two ANOVA tables.

Comment: The reference model is different. In the model with intercept, it is the overall mean. In the model without intercept, it is 0.

Comment: @MichaelM That is a exciting explanation. Would you mind making it an answer?

Comment: @MichaelM thanks for answering, gave me chance to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour indeed leads to confusion from time to time.   It is an implementation decision of R.

The reason is as follows:

The reference model is different. In the model with intercept, it is the overall mean. In the model without intercept, it is 0. That is also the reason why sum of squared are very different across the two models.

Comment: Thank you, that's an answer in the direction of clearing up my confusion. However, I still don't understand what the R ANOVA table shows, because in my mind it's not what one typically means by an ANOVA table. For example ```sum(lmIntercept$residuals^2) == anova(lmIntercept)$`Sum Sq`[2]``` returns `FALSE`. Is there any documentation on what the R ANOVA table actually shows, because clearly it does not show e.g. sum of squared residuals.